# Show that an induced map on a quotient space is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Consider the unit square $Q := [0,1] \times [0,1]$ with the coordinates $(x,y) \in Q$. Let $Z := Q/\thicksim$ be the quotient space, which results by identifying:
\begin{align*}
  (x, 0) & \thicksim (x,1), x \in [0,1] \\
  (0, y) & \thicksim (1, 1 - y), y \in (0,1).
\end{align*}
Consider the function $f: Q \to K$,
$$
  (x,y) \mapsto (A(y)\cos(2\pi x), A(y) \sin(2\pi x), B(y) \cos(\pi x), B(y)\sin(\pi x))
$$
with $A(y) := r\cos(2\pi y) + a, B(y) := r \sin(2\pi y)$ and real constants $0 < r < a$. Show that the by $f$ induced map $g: Z \to K$ is a homoemorphism.

First I thought that because the $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions are homeomorph on $[0,2\pi]$, it is enought to show that $f(x,0) = f(x,1)$ and $f(0,y) = f(1,1-y)$. But $\cos$ and $\sin$ are not injective, so thery are no homormophism. Any tips how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is $K$? I assume it's some embedding of the Klein bottle in $\mathbb{R}^4$? In any case, recall that if $h\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection from a compact space $X$ to a Hausdorff space $Y$, then $h$ is a homeomorphism. In your case, $g$ is induced by $f$ so is automatically continuous. You just need to show that $g$ is a bijection. This is best done by noting where $f$ fails to be injective and then showing that these 'double points' are identified in the quotient and so induce an injective map. Also, $f$ is surjective (show this) and so $g$ is immediately surjective.